# Can't understand the requirement of the problem. (ProjectEuler problem: 11)

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, math

I am trying to solve this problem: https://projecteuler.net/problem=11
However, this part confuses me:

> What is the greatest product of four adjacent numbers in the same
> direction (up, down, left, right, or diagonally) in the 20×20 grid?

what does `in the same direction` and `up, down, left, right or diagonally` mean?
Is it just me or is the language vague here?

this is what I have tried so far:

```
long int prod{0}, n{20};

for(int i{0}; i <= n; i++) {
    for(int j{0}; j <= n; j++) {
        long int a{grid[i][j]}, b{grid[i+1][j+1]}, c{grid[i+2][j+2]}, d{grid[i+3][j+3]};
        if(prod < (a * b * c * d))
            prod = a * b * c * d;
    }
}

return prod;
```

With this function I satisfy the first demand but up down left right or diagonally? what does `or` mean there?

Comment: `up` and `down` are the same; `left` and `right` are the same; `diagonally` can be like / or \. You need to test 4 directions in all.

Comment: It means that if you draw a line through the four numbers, they must all be next to each other on the same line: horizontal, diagonal, or vertical. The four numbers in red give an example for 'diagonal', and it can be the *other* diagonal too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A direction in the context of a grid is the geometrical space whose all points are on the same line.

If we take a point, then we can cross it with 4 different lines:

```
\   |   /
 \  |  /
  \ | /
   \|/
----*----
   /|\
  / | \
 /  |  \
/   |   \
```

So, how could we define these directions? There is a very simple way to do so:

- you loop the rows

  - you loop the columns

    - at the current point, you try to get 4 values, including the current point

      - downwards
      - rightwards
      - right-downwards
      - right-upwards

I say "try", which means that you will have to ignore quite a few possibilities due to the boundaries of your grid. Yet, it is a neat way to get all four directions:

```
int bestProduct = -1; //Assuming you have positives
for (int row = 0; row < n; row++) {
    for (int column = 0; column < n; column++) {
        int ignore = 0;
        int rowDir = 0;
        int colDir = 1;
        int product = grid[row][column];
        for (int index = 0; (!ignore) && (index < 3); index++) {
            if (
                   (row + rowDir < 0) ||
                   (row + rowDir >= n) ||
                   (column + colDir < 0) ||
                   (column + colDir >= m)
               ) {
                ignore = 1;
            }
            else product *= grid[row + rowDir][column + colDir];
        }
        if ((!ignore) && (bestProduct < product)) bestProduct = product;
    }
}
```

This is not a full implementation, since you also need to do some work. You will need to continue with:

- converting the inner part of the second loop into a function except the `if` conditional that checks whether the product is higher than the best product so far
- remove that inner code and replace it with the function call
- call the function three more times, once for each other direction
- the other directions are:

  - 1: having a 1 `colDir` and 0 `rowDir`
  - 2: having a 1 `colDir` and 1 `rowDir`
  - 3: having a 1 `colDir` and -1 `rowDir`

I know it is more difficult to consider this partial solution, but it will help you a lot in the long run if you do the rest for yourself, as the ideas are all laid down here.

Answer (score 2):

You need to check each row, column, and diagonal of 4. This means you need to check:

```
from grid[i-4][j] to grid[i][j]  
from grid[i][j-4] to grid[i][j]  
from grid[i-4][j-4] to grid[i][j] (diagonal) 
from grid[i+4][j-4] to grid[i][j] (other diagonal)
```

Make sure to watch for the grid sides too as if you're on the very left, you'll need to look to the right

Comment: @SupportUkraine: checking "a\*b\*c\*d" is the same as checking "d\*c\*b\*a". IMHO checking 4 products is easier than checking 8 :) ... and it avoids repetitions

Comment: @SupportUkraine: The other 4 are the same, except for on edges, since you are finding the product (which is commutative). looking behind by 4 paces is equivalent to looking in front by 4 paces when 4 paces behind.

Comment: @SupportUkraine ... https://i2.paste.pics/4fcd98f5fc4bd993614eeac97cccb0f5.png

Comment: That's a question of algorithm: not to check one set when you've already checked it from the other end.

Comment: @SupportUkraine no it, is not missing. Basically there are four lines crossing the given point. One can choose to only check four lines while looping the grid. This answer is correct.

Comment: @SupportUkraine since the question was about understanding what a direction means in a grid, it is technically answering the question, this is why I have upvoted this answer.

Comment: @SupportUkraine let's consider point (4, 4). I suppose that by the 8 lines you mean (1, 1)-(4, 4), (4, 4)-(7, 7), (1, 4)-(4, 4), (4, 4)-(7, 4), (4, 1)-(4, 4), (4, 4)-(4, 7), (1, 7)-(4, 4) and (4, 4)-(7, 1). I have listed these in order to make sure that we are on the same page. Now, I say that when we are at (4, 4), for example we take account (4, 4)-(7, 7), but we do not take into account (1, 1)-(4, 4) at this point, because that case was already taken account in an earlier stage of the loop, when we are at point (1, 1).

Comment: @SupportUkraine so, if we take into account (r, c), (r + 1, c + 1), (r + 2, c + 2), (r + 3, c + 3) as a direction when we are at (r, c), but we do not take into account the negative at this point, then we do not miss anything, because, when we were at (r - 3, c -3), then we have already taken into account the direction you have been speaking about.